# Multiple cards inside a listview in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am a beginner in Flutter. I want to add another card in the listview mentioned in the following code.

```
  Widget section4 = Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
  child:Card(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        const ListTile(
          leading: FlutterLogo(size: 56.0),
          title: Text('Item 1'),
          subtitle: Text('Item 1 subtitle'),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    
  ),
);
```

I tried with this but it is showing error. Also, is there a way where I can create this list using a loop in Flutter?

```
Widget section4 = Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
  child:Card(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        const ListTile(
          leading: FlutterLogo(size: 56.0),
          title: Text('Item 1'),
          subtitle: Text('Item 1 subtitle'),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Card(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        const ListTile(
          leading: FlutterLogo(size: 56.0),
          title: Text('Item 1'),
          subtitle: Text('Item 1 subtitle'),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a `ListView.builder()` like so:

```
ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 3, // the length
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                child: Card(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const ListTile(
                        leading: FlutterLogo(size: 56.0),
                        title: Text('Item 1'),
                        subtitle: Text('Item 1 subtitle'),
                        trailing: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            })
```

or if you want to keep the Widgets in a separate list, you can also do this:

```
 List<Widget> section4 = [
     Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
  child:Card(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        const ListTile(
          leading: FlutterLogo(size: 56.0),
          title: Text('Item 1'),
          subtitle: Text('Item 1 subtitle'),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    
  ),
),
      Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
  child:Card(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        const ListTile(
          leading: FlutterLogo(size: 56.0),
          title: Text('Item 1'),
          subtitle: Text('Item 1 subtitle'),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    
  ),
),
      Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
  child:Card(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        const ListTile(
          leading: FlutterLogo(size: 56.0),
          title: Text('Item 1'),
          subtitle: Text('Item 1 subtitle'),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    
  ),
)
     ];
```

Then just put it inside a widget that has the *children* property:

```
 body:  Column(
                children: section4
          
)
```

Comment: After using ListView.builder(), I am getting exception from the rendering library.
1. The getter 'scrollOffsetCorrection' was called on null.
2. The method 'debugAssertIsValid' was called on null.
3. The getter 'visible' was called on null.

Comment: That might be something else from your other code. Those errors that you're getting usually happen when you don't initialize a list.

Comment: Thanks. it is working now after adding shrinkWrap: true inside ListView.builder.

Comment: Is there a way to index the item? All the entries are shown as Item 1 with the same subtitle.

Comment: replace 1 in the Text widget with $index (the value passed in the build function)